2 Between-subjects, and 2 Within-subjects, and 2 DV
My data contains the following characteristics:

Between-subjects factor: Group (Intervention A vs. Intervention B)
Within-subjects factor: Time (Pre vs. Post)
Dependent variables: Anxiety (Scale A) and behaviour (Scale B)
Individuals: 48

Which data analysis you would recommend for this data?

I assume your goal is to see whether change from pre to post in your dependent variables differs between groups? If so, and you want to only run one model, I'd use a multilevel structural equation model (e.g. in MPlus the two-level random type).
If you're comfortable running separate models of the two outcomes, you could use a multilevel regression predicting each outcome in turn from group, time, and their interaction, with a random intercept of participant.
Alternatives would be repeated-measures/mixed ANOVA with group as between- and time as within-subjects factor (though I'd recommend rather using a multilevel model, because it gives you the same information but has more flexible assumptions), or ANCOVA with group as between-subjects factor, post-scores as dependent variable, and pre-scores as a covariate.
I answered assuming your dependent variables are continuous, as anxiety scores typically are, but you have included "categorical data" tag, suggesting that may not be the case. If your outcomes are binary, one option is multilevel logistic regression.
